# Upgrading Application to Rails 4 issues with client_side_validations-formtastic gem

Tags: rubygems, ruby-on-rails-4

Upgrading Application to Rails 4 issues with `client_side_validations-formtastic` gem
Bundle install is giving an issue:

```
client_side_validations-formtastic (>= 0) ruby depends on
formtastic (~> 2.0.0) ruby

activeadmin (>= 0) ruby depends on
  formtastic (2.3.0.rc2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately we can not always follow [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/) everytime so instead of declaring a dependency with `~> 2.0` we have to stick to a much *secure* dependency like `~> 2.0.0`.

I've already sent a [pull request](https://github.com/dockyard/client_side_validations-formtastic/pull/14) to solve your issue to [client_side_validations-formtastic](https://github.com/dockyard/client_side_validations-formtastic).

In the meantime you can use my patch as a source for the gem, within your `Gemfile` and also ensure you include activeadmin from latest (still unreleased) master:

```
$ vim Gemfile

gem 'client_side_validations-formtastic', github: 'elgalu/client_side_validations-formtastic', branch: 'patch-1'
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin', ref: 'a08c84f7c228'
gem 'rails', '4.0.2'

$ bundle update

#=> Fetching git://github.com/elgalu/client_side_validations-formtastic.git
#=> Fetching git://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git
#=> ...
#=> Installing formtastic (2.3.0.rc2)
#=> Using activeadmin (1.0.0.pre) from git://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git (at a08c84f)
#=> Using client_side_validations-formtastic (2.2.0) from git://github.com/elgalu/client_side_validations-formtastic.git (at patch-1)
#=> Your bundle is complete!
```

Comment: Your setup works with client_side_validations and formtastic? I am getting a "wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)" error for form_for after rails4 upgrade and even with the above gem setup.

Comment: Is not fully tested and i'm no maintaining the fork anymore. You should put some extra work to make it work now or try opening issues in the original project repository.